# how to uninstall certbot in CentOS

Tags: centos, certbot

LetsEncrypt's certbot is not supported on CentOS. However, after installing this, the VPS kept warning me

```
    
The filesystem “/var/lib/snapd/snap/certbot/1434” mounted at “/var/lib/snapd/snap/certbot/1434” reached “critical” status because you currently use 100% of its available inodes.
```

So I want to unstall this. Do you know how? Thank you!

Comment: please, read the error message carefully and think about problem it reports, not about certbot

Comment: This error indeed has nothing to do with cerbot, I found another folder under snapd triggers this error. So I guess the culprit is snapd, which is for certbot. But since GoDaddy doesn't support ACME protocol. I don't want snapd and certbot. So my question is how to uninstall them.

Comment: Uhm, no. The culprit is that you are running out of inodes. Your disk is full.

Comment: certbot works perfectly on CentOS. It is in EPEL. You should _not_ use the snap.

Comment: Certbot is supported on CentOS. The issue is that GoDaddy does not support Let's Encrypt certificate issuance and renewals (ACME). You can issue a certificate using DNS validation and then install the certificate manually. That also means renewing the certificate manually. Suggestion: when a vendor does not support the industry and community, file a support ticket. If they do not listen, move to a different vendor. The money you might be saving will be lost supporting problems like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to remove `snapd` and `certbot`. Not sure if the server can be quieter. If still not works, I will update this answer.

I couldn't remember how I install the certbot and snapd, so I check the LetsEncypt install page. (https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-apache)

```
sudo yum remove certbot
```

uninstall snap (https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-centos)

```
sudo yum remove snapd
rm -rf /var/lib/snapd/snap 
rm -rf /snap
```